# How to unhide a batch file

Tags: windows-8, batch-file

I am trying to make a `.bat` script that will unhide another `.bat` file in the same folder only once. I am making an auto backup for a game, but first I want the user to agree to Terms of Use and Disclaimer. I have the password set (yes/no) but I don't know how to make the other `.bat` unhidden without it toggling back and forth between hidden and unhidden.

How would I do this? I know about locker but I want both `.bat` files in the same folder. I am grateful for any help.

Comment: Is the problem you are having that your first batch file unhides the second, but when you run the second it unhides the first? Or it is something else?

Answer (score 0):

From your first batch file you can unhide your second batch file with the command

```
ATTRIB MySecondFile.BAT -H
```

It doesn't matter how many times you run this command, it will leave the second batch file unhidden.